# Указатель на this в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сейчас часто стал использовать в jquery такой стиль написание обработки событий

```
var item = {
    'add': function(){},
    'remove': function(){}
}
```

На кнопку навешиваю событие

```
onclick="item.add();"
```

Как мне в функции получить ссылку на this? Сейчас я добавляю переменную в функцию, например

```
'add': function(self){}
```

а при вызове пишу так

```
onclick="item.add($(this));"
```

Есть возможность это сделать проще?

Comment: можно вызывать в самом jquery `$(elem).click(function(){//this = кнопка})`

Answer (score 1):

[event.target](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_target.asp)

```js
var item = {
  'add': function() {
    console.log('some adding action on ' + event.target.name);
  },
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="me-imput" onclick="item.add()">
```

**UPD** (thx->to(Igor,tutankhamun))**:**

У данного подхода несовместимость с firefox - он до сих пор определяет event только как параметр обработчика. И получается, что подход, используемый вами, сбалансирован.

Comment: Не взлетит. Откуда возьмется `event`?

Comment: @tutankhamun скорее всего от onclick

Comment: в Firefox нет глобального объекта `event`

Comment: В Javascript в функции видны переменные, которые 1) определены внутри функции, 2) переданы в качестве аргументов 3) определены в месте определения самой функции. Глобальный `event`, есть не везде. Поэтому придется передавать его явно

Comment: Igor и tutankhamun - спасибо.